# PyVista add_volume shows a blank image

Tags: python, 3d, visualization, pyvista

I am trying to develop some data visualizations with PyVista (on a mac). My Python version is 3.7.4 and my PyVista (installed via conda) is 0.25.1. I tried the example provided here: https://banesullivan.com/python-blog/000-intro-to-pyvista.html#sphx-glr-download-python-blog-000-intro-to-pyvista-py. For the two `add_volume` examples, it just shows a blank screen. 
[image]

The `add_mesh` example shows up fine.
[image]

I am not sure how to get the `add_volume` visualizations to show up. Any help would be much appreciated.

Update: If I directly try to save a screenshot, the image is saved:

```
p = pv.Plotter(off_screen=True)
p.add_volume(model, cmap="magma", clim=clim,
             opacity=opacity, opacity_unit_distance=6000,)
p.show(screenshot='volcano.png')
```

[image]

However, I would like to be able to display the image in the interactive window, as that allows panning, rotating, and zooming.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. You should probably make sure you have the latest pyvista and vtk, and if the problem remains you should consider opening an issue on the pyvista github repo.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did open an issue on the pyvista github repo: https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista-support/issues/175